# Is every real root also a complex root? (Complex zeros and Fundamental Theorem of Algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Stupid question about this topic:  I don't understand the rule that says "A poly with degree N will have N complex roots".   eg:  $P(X)=x^5 + x^3 - 1$ is a 5th degree polynomial function, so P(x) has exactly 5 complex zeros.  Sorry, but how do you know it will have 5 ***complex*** zeros?  Maybe it factors into only real/integer roots?   Or, is every real root also a complex root?  ie:  $x = x + 0i$

What is a complex polynomial function (which has at least one complex zero)?  Just a poly with an "i" in the coefficient?  eg:  $4ix^2 + ...$

***Disclaimer: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus from a textbook. I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

Comment: Real roots are special complex roots, those with imaginary part $0$. The mention of "complex" only indicates that one doesn't have to leave $\mathbb{C}$ to find the zeros.

Comment: Your textbook should also say something about the roots being "counted according to their multiplicity". $(x - 1)^2(x - i)^2$ is a polynomial of degree 4 with just 2 distinct roots, $1$ and $i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, real numbers are complex numbers with imaginary part $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Every real number is a complex number. You aren't guaranteed that every n-degree polynomial will have n roots, i.e. x^2+1= 0 has no REAL roots but two complex roots, namely -i and i. x^2-1=0 has two complex roots as well, 1 and -1, they just happen to have no imaginary part and are thus entirely real.

Answer (score 2):

The real numbers are a subset of the complex numbers ($\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$), so any element of the reals is also complex.